# Lead Field Mapping Permissions

Tags: custom-field, permissions, leads, lead-conversion, field-mapping

I couldn't find the specifics on this but when a user converts a Lead do they need access to Standard and Custom Fields they are mapping to or do conversions run in the System context? I have some Custom Fields on Lead and Contact that I don't want users to have edit access to, but I do want to mapped from Lead to Contact. These are external fields I use with API resources.

For instance I have an external identifier named UserId that I want mapped from Lead to Contact when converted, but I don't want to give the user more than read access.

Answer (score 1):

Lead mapping is run in the system context if you are speaking of out of the box file mapping

I cannot find specific documentation stating that it will but all triggers, etc run in system context and if it did not imagine the data skew that would exist when leads are converted.